# How to access resources in my spring boot app from angular 5 app?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security

I created a Spring Boot project.Student Managment System.
I have Rest Controller for basic crud operations.And I secured it with basic Auth.No table for users,just in application properties I specified username and password for Spring Security.

With Postman,everything works fine.

Now,I have created angular app for front end,with login page.My question is how to check if inserted username and password is equal with spring boot security credentials?I mean,if it is,how to connect to the server with this credentials?

Comment: https://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-angular-example

Answer (score 0):

I think that if spring security is enabled, it should already have created a /login ressource and a login page and you shouldn't be able to access any pages of your app (exept if you add http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers()) if you're not logged in.

Comment: Yes,I know that.I am asking for my angular app.I have created components for login and display student info.Now I only need to connect with my backend,which is secured with basic auth,to be able to see list of students...Thanks for answer.